# ionic serve bug with @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular in ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, command-line-interface, ionic3

I just ran into this bug while trying to run my ionic3 app in my browser. I have recently migrated from ionic2 to ionic3 and it was quite smooth. After a few runs, this bug came up.

```
C:\Users\Emeka\Documents\Current Project\Freelance>ionic serve

[ERROR] An error occurred while running npm view @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular dist-tags.latest --json (exit code 1):
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! errno ENOENT
    npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
    npm ERR! enoent getaddrinfo ENOENT registry.npmjs.org:443
    npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    npm ERR! enoent
    {
      "error": {
        "code": "ENOENT",
        "summary": "getaddrinfo ENOENT registry.npmjs.org:443",
        "detail": "This is related to npm not being able to find a file.\n"
      }
    }

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Emeka\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-09T21_18_38_802Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem after looking up a link -- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic/app-scripts

> First I ran npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev

```
C:\Users\Emeka\Documents\Current Project\Freelance>npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
npm WARN deprecated object-keys@0.2.0: Please update to the latest object-keys
+ @ionic/app-scripts@1.3.7
added 63 packages, removed 9 packages and updated 1 package in 118.187s
```

Then considering the warning I had to update my object-keys to the latest version

```
C:\Users\Emeka\Documents\Current Project\Freelance>npm install object-keys@latest --save-dev
+ object-keys@1.0.11
updated 1 package in 30.535s
```

> Finally I tried my ionic serve again and it was fine without errors

```
C:\Users\Emeka\Documents\Current Project\Freelance>ionic serve
[INFO] Starting app-scripts server: --port 8100 --p 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --r 35729 --address 0.0.0.0 - Ctrl+C to cancel
[23:13:09]  watch started ...
[23:13:09]  build dev started ...
[23:13:09]  clean started ...
[23:13:10]  clean finished in 104 ms
[23:13:10]  copy started ...
[23:13:10]  transpile started ...
[23:13:23]  transpile finished in 13.17 s
[23:13:23]  preprocess started ...
[23:13:23]  deeplinks started ...
[23:13:23]  deeplinks finished in 169 ms
[23:13:23]  preprocess finished in 185 ms
[23:13:23]  webpack started ...
[23:13:25]  copy finished in 15.44 s
[23:13:39]  webpack finished in 16.25 s
[23:13:39]  sass started ...
[23:13:49]  sass finished in 10.25 s
[23:13:49]  postprocess started ...
[23:13:50]  postprocess finished in 70 ms
[23:13:50]  lint started ...
[23:13:50]  build dev finished in 40.20 s
[23:13:50]  watch ready in 40.95 s
[23:13:50]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u try deleting ur node-modules directory and running `npm install` again?